# Is there out-of-the box validator for Enum values in DataAnnotations namespace?

Tags: c#, enums, data-annotations

C# enum values are not limited to only values listed in it's definition and may store any value of it's base type. If base type is not defined than `Int32` or simply `int` is used.

I am developing a WCF serivice which needs to be confident that some enum has a value assigned as opposed to the default value for all enums of 0. I start with a unit test to find out whether `[Required]` would do right job here.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Xunit;

public enum MyEnum
{
    // I always start from 1 in order to distinct first value from the default value
    First = 1,
    Second,
}

public class Entity
{
    [Required]
    public MyEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
}

public class EntityValidationTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestValidEnumValue()
    {
        Entity entity = new Entity { EnumValue = MyEnum.First };

        Validator.ValidateObject(entity, new ValidationContext(entity, null, null));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestInvalidEnumValue()
    {
        Entity entity = new Entity { EnumValue = (MyEnum)(-126) };
        // -126 is stored in the entity.EnumValue property

        Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() =>
            Validator.ValidateObject(entity, new ValidationContext(entity, null, null)));
    }
}
```

It does not, the second test does not throw any exception.

My question is: is there a validator attribute to check that supplied value is in `Enum.GetValues`?

**Update**.
Make sure to use the `ValidateObject(Object, ValidationContext, Boolean)` with last parameter equal to `True` instead of `ValidateObject(Object, ValidationContext)` as done in my unit test.

Comment: I never used it, so I don't know if it checks for the values, but you could try EnumDataTypeAttribute : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.enumdatatypeattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's [EnumDataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.enumdatatypeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in .NET4+ ...

Make sure you set the 3rd parameter, `validateAllProperties=true` in the call to `ValidateObject`

so from your example:

```
public class Entity
{
    [EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum))]
    public MyEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void TestInvalidEnumValue()
{
    Entity entity = new Entity { EnumValue = (MyEnum)(-126) };
    // -126 is stored in the entity.EnumValue property

    Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() =>
        Validator.ValidateObject(entity, new ValidationContext(entity, null, null), true));
}
```

Comment: Just switched from `[Required]` to `[EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum))]` and tested, still no `ValidationException`

Comment: Have you tried adding true as the 3rd parameter to the ValidateObject call?

Comment: Good point! Now it works. There's only `[EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum))]`, no `[Required]` and I call `ValidateObject` with `validateAllProperties=true`. Could you please update your answer showing the correct validation approach so I could accept it?

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is:

```
 Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), entity.EnumValue)
```

**[Update+1]**

The out of the box validator that does a lot of validations including this one is called EnumDataType. Make sure you set validateAllProperties=true as ValidateObject, otherwise your test will fail.

If you just want to check if the enum is defined, you can use a custom validator with the above line:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class EnumValidateExistsAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
    {
        public EnumValidateExistsAttribute(Type enumType)
            : base("Enumeration")
        {
            this.EnumType = enumType;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (this.EnumType == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Type cannot be null");
            }
            if (!this.EnumType.IsEnum)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Type must be an enum");
            }
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(EnumType, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public Type EnumType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

... but I suppose it's not out of the box then is it?

Comment: +1 for this helpful method. It has been there for years, but I've never noticed it

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you're absolutely right. Sorry for that, changed my answer and tested it, this works.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn fine and +1

Comment: You can simply `return Enum.IsDefined(EnumType, value)` on last step

Comment: Thanks for effort guys. It turns out the `EnumDataType` does its job. I just had to include `validateAllProperties=true`

Comment: This is probably no big deal, but why not use the `ValidationContext` to get the type of enum automatically? Or even better, simply use `value.GetType()`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my need simply based on this website https://kristinaalberto.com/making-enum-parameters-required-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

```
    public enum CreatedBySelfOrOthersEnumValues
    {
        Self,
        Others
    }

  
    public class CampaignRegisterValidationModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public CreatedBySelfOrOthersEnumValues CreatedForSelfOrOthers { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CountryCode { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Then validating

```
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
     }
```