# Invalid enum value

Tags: c#, parameters, enums, asp.net-web-api2

So I have a type:

```
public enum Types
{
    aaa= 1,
    bbb= 2,
    ccc= 4
}

public class RequestPayload
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public Types Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

And with Postman I am testing a web api.

```
public MyType Create([FromBody] RequestPayloadpayload)
{
    return null
}
```

Here are my postman settings:

[image]

So why in the controller my object has property `Prop3` to 6666 when my enum does not have this value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating Enum Values within C# MVC. Partial validation occurs - How to change validation behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425242/validating-enum-values-within-c-sharp-mvc-partial-validation-occurs-how-to-ch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about "postman", but I assume you're surprised that an int value other than 1, 2, or 4 can be assigned to `Prop3`.  The reason is - that's just how enums work in C# since, under the hood, a field of an enum type is converted to an `int` (or whatever the underlying type of the enum is), any `int` value can legally be stored in it.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> ```
> enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
> ```
>
> A variable of type `Days` can be assigned any value in the range of
>   the underlying type; the values are not limited to the named
>   constants.

This is *probably* to avoid expensive run-time checking of values against "defined" values, but there may be other architectural reasons as well (the use of "flag" enums is one that comes to mind).

Comment: Indeed, I was surprised that I can assign other values to mu enum.