# ASP.NET Custom ErrorMessage for Model Enum field

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-2.1, validationattribute, ivalidatableobject

I am developing a website built on EntityFrameworkCore and targeting ASP.NET Core 2.1.  I want to specify an error message for an enum field in my model like so:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select an item from the list.")]
public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
```

However, the stock message is still generated: `The value '0' is invalid`.  The problem appears to be that the Enum type is validated prior to any of my code being evaluated.  The two approaches presented here (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204077/ASP-NET-Core-MVC-Model-Validation), either creating a class that inherits from ValidationAttribute, or having the model inherit from IValidatableObject both suffer from this.

I have found a workaround: declare the field as an int, and then use a custom validation attribute:

```cs
[EnumCheck(typeof(MyEnum), ErrorMessage = "Select an item form the list.")]
public int MyEnum { get; set; }
```

...and then subclass from ValidationAttribute:

```cs
sealed public class EnumCheck : ValidationAttribute
{
    readonly Type t_;

    public EnumCheck(Type t)
    {
        t_ = t;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return Enum.IsDefined(t_, value);
    }
}
```

This approach has some drawbacks as now I need to cast the field to the Enum type in many places that it is used.

Is there a way to provide an ErrorMessage for Enum field types?

**UPDATE**

The following is a minimal example (No longer using EnumCheck subclass from ValidationAttribute, but rather the EnumDataType mentioned by @PéterCsajtai):

Model

```
namespace web.Models
{
    public enum Day
    {
        Sunday = 1,
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday
    }

    public class Form
    {
        [EnumDataType(typeof(Day), ErrorMessage = "Select an item from the list.")]
        public Day Day { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Save(Form model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index");
            }

            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<form asp-controller="Home">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <label asp-for="@Model.Day"></label>
        <select asp-for="@Model.Day" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Day>()">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
        </select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Day)
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Day" class="text-danger"></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" asp-action="Save" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the output after form post:

[image: form output]

Comment: Enum is an int. Maybe 0 is your problem. Have you tried to set the first enum at 1?

Comment: @Manta Yes I have.  In fact, that's how I first noticed the issue.  MyEnum is populated form a select box, which at first only contained each element form the enum.  I then decided I waned a 'Choose One...' option at the top of the list, and set its value to 0.

Comment: Sort of feels like you are searching for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14381564/125981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In your original case, `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select an item from the list.")]` you are setting the message to be shown if `MyEnum` is missing. But like all ValueTypes, it can **never** be missing so it will never trigger that validation. The solution for this is the nullable ValueType.
- Your second effort still doesn't work because the *model-binding* failure – "Can a blank value be converted to a `Day`? No it can't." kicks in before your *validation* can kick in.

Validation for a `Type` presupposes that you have an `instance` of that `Type` to validate. The way Aspnetcore turns a form post into that typed value, is modelbinding. If the posted value can't be model-bound -- for instance if you post "boo" to a property declared as an `int`, or an empty string to an `Enum` -- then *validation* never even starts. Instead the *modelbinding* error is shown.

The simple solution is

- Use a **nullable enum**, `Day?` so that  *modelbinding* a blank succeeds (blank resolves to `null`).
- Use `[Required()]` so that that `null` value then fails validation.

Conclusion: change your form to:

```
public class Form
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select an item from the list.")]
    public Day? Day { get; set; }
}
```

And then it will work as you'd expect.

Reference: [Model Validation in AspNet Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#notes-on-the-use-of-the-required-attribute)

NB unlike other `ValidationAttributes`, the [documentation for `EnumDataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.enumdatatypeattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), although it inherits from ValidationAttribute, doesn't give an example of using it for validation. Instead the example is of using it for MetaData.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for the `EnumDataTypeAttribute`:

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum), ErrorMessage = "Select an item form the list.")]
public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is useful, it appears to do exactly what my `EnumCheck` attribute class does, so I can remove that.  However, if I declare the field as `public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set;}` then I get the `The value '0' is invalid` message rather than the specified `ErrorMessage`.  I still have to declare the field as an int.

Comment: That is weird, i got the proper validation message in my sample project, how do you make the validation exactly?

Comment: Exactly as you have it.  I've gone and made a new soultion/project as a minimal example with the same results.  Perhaps I need a different method of displaying the error?  I have tried both:

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyEnum)` and `<span asp-validation-for="@Model.MyEnum" class="text-danger"></span>`

Comment: I think this plan will never work. If the posted value can't be turned into an enum, then the ValidationAttributes are never reached. The error happens a stage earlier, in the model-binding. If the posted value _can_ be turned into an enum, then validation always passes! Either way, this ValidationAttribute can never return a fail.

Answer (score 0):

Define Your Model:

```
public enum Day
{
    None=0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
}
```

and then define your Custome Validation Attribute:

```
sealed public class EnumCheck : ValidationAttribute
  {
    readonly Type t_;

    public EnumCheck(Type t)
     {
       t_ = t;
     }

   public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

      if (((int)value)==0)
        {
            return false;

        }
      return Enum.IsDefined(t_, value);
    }
}
```

and finally use from this in your view:

```
<form asp-controller="Home">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<fieldset>
    <label asp-for="@Model.Day"></label>
    <select asp-for="@Model.Day" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Day>()">
        <option value="0">Select...</option>
    </select>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Day)
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Day" class="text-danger"></span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input type="submit" asp-action="Save" />
</fieldset>
```